# how to deactivate "dictate" (microphone symbol) key completley

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I would like to use the Microphone Symbol above F5 Button as Mute Button in my Voice call application of choice.

I have deactivated the dictate functions in 'system preferences/keyboard' in tab 'dictate'. (MacOS 12.1 direct German translation)
After that, dictate stopped to work directly, but instead I get a window popup that asks me to activate it if I want to use it with the choice of 'Later' or 'OK' that leads to the activation process.

How can I deactivate 'dictate' completely from the hotkey with the Microphone symbol?

[image: Do you want to activate Dictate functions?]

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine with changing the behavior of all function keys, you can do it turning **System Preferences → Keyboard → Use F1, F2, etc. as standard function keys.**

You can also press **F5** when holding the **fn** key to use the opposite behavior of what is set.

If you want to change the default behavior of only this one key, you have to download and install [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org), then remap **f5** to **f5** in the **Function Keys** tab.